# The correct way to make functions interact with each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm writing a very basic application. I can make it work in two ways:

1. ```
   def a():
       xxxxx
       return data

   def b():
       data = a()
       //use data in function
       return yyy

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       output = b()
       print(output)
   ```
2. ```
   def a():
       xxxxx
       return data

   def b(data):
       return yyy

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       data = a()
       output = b(data)
       print(output)
   ```

I'm searching for some good information or docs about how to create your functions. Both my examples above do work but how should you make functions interact with each other? I would think it's not correct to use the `main` function to call nearly every function and return it there, but also the first example seems a bit weird to me since function `b` fully depends on `a` without parameter.

Is there some clear explanation or guide on how to do this?

Comment: In your first example, `b` is forced to get its input from `a`. The second version makes it independant. Independance is good.

Answer (score 2):

Independence is better - you can reuse `b` with other data (say a `c()` that generates some other data). It is also more clear what happens - `b` operates on data you put in, not some "magical" connection to `a`.

If you changed `a()` you might also have to change `b()` to still be able to use `a()` - thats tight coupling ([more...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29)) and generally not desirable.

If you really have hard dependencies, and just want to put less code per function, consider inner functions:

```
def getStringOfNumbersTimes2(numbers):
    """Returns a string containing the input numbers multiplicated by 2"""
    def mult2():
        """Mults each number by 2."""
        return [n*2 for n in numbers]

    # create the string - with : in between numbers
    return ' : '.join(map(str,mult2()))

print(getStringOfNumbersTimes2([1,2,3]))
print(getStringOfNumbersTimes2([9.42,8.31,7.2]))
```

Output:

```
2 : 4 : 6
18.84 : 16.62  :14.4
```

This is a contreived example - I would only do this if I never need `mult2` outside of `getStringOfNumbersTimes2` and want to have `getStringOfNumbersTimes2` only ever output twice what I give it.

Answer (score 1):

All always depends of the use case you are working on.

But, in the example you shared above, I'd like to say that the second option is better, since then the methods `a` and `b` are independent.

The benefits of the option 2 is that then you are able to re-use the methods in multiple scenarios, so `b` now it's just expecting `data`, even if it comes from `a` or for another future method. And the data from `a` will be able to be used in multiple places too.

Moreover, the second option makes easier to write unit tests in isolation for each function, and looks like the kind of implementation you will end with in case you are using TDD.

I hope it helps.